# Copy webview instance to other uiwebview instance

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a webview and I need to copy to a uiwebview variable or instance. But it's crashing at that point.

The crash is:

> [uiwebview copywithZone:] unrecognized selector sent.

Answer (score 1):

copywithzone method didnot work with uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

Once check that, have you used any method named `copyWithZone`. because of that only, it is giving error. why because, the UIWebView doesn't support that method.

Comment: No , i did not..... i used webview1=[webview2 copy] .  Can u tell how to copy an uiwebview instance.

Comment: you can retain the webView Object, by using webview1=[webview2 retain]

Comment: Satya: With ARC, there are no retain function. So is there any way to "retain"?